# visualizing enter symbol in java applet (fonts or graphics?)

Tags: java, applet, awt

How can I display the graphical "enter symbol" within java applet ?

I want to show exactly  "↵", which is U+21B5 DOWNWARDS ARROW WITH CORNER LEFTWARDS. –

I want to draw this to applet's screen so that it works in WIN, LINUX, MACOSX, etc.

Is there a font available that makes this possible or should I draw it somehow, how ?

```
g2d.setFont("SymbolFont??which one");
g2d.drawString(myenterSymbolHere,x,Y);
```

Answer (score 2):

CRLF is not a single character. They are CR (carriage return) and LF (line feed) characters that together represent a newline in the Windows world (most other systems use just LF).

They don't have any "official" graphical representation, because they are control characters.

You might be referring to the [Pilcrow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pilcrow) (¶, U+00B6), which is sometimes used to represent a newline (even though it actually indicates the end of a paragraph). Whether or not this character is available depends entirely on the font, but it is fairly widely available.

Comment: is there a website listing all these characters available? with their U+codes

Comment: I am looking after a character that looks like <- enter symbol used in keyboard, there is one e.g. in Windows SYMBOL font #191

Comment: Start here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode, the page contains a lot of links to tables and overviews

Comment: You might want "↵", which is U+21B5 DOWNWARDS ARROW WITH CORNER LEFTWARDS.

Comment: U+21B5  sounds excellent,  but how can I draw it to java applet's screen with drawString()

Comment: I get just a box with drawscreen("\u21b5")

Comment: Use `"\u21b5"` as the String literal. You can represent any Unicode anywhere in your source code using the `\u` escapes.

Comment: If you get a box, then the font just doesn't support it. Use another font (or another character).

Comment: any ideas what font will support this 21b5 ?  a font that is found from all computers running java,  WIN, MAC, LINUX

Comment: @Tom: when you get a box that means that the font you use doesn't provide a glyph for that codepoint. Switch to another font or draw the symbol manually.

Comment: @Tom: i don't think there's even a single font that's available on all platforms, let alone one that supports a wide array of unicode glyphs.

Comment: OK; I will adjust my question a little

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this,

## ␍␊

It's part of Unicode control symbols and you can find it here,

http://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2400.pdf